# Why is the pointer displaying the value and not the address?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, pointers, c++17

I have this code:

```
int *array_ptr{nullptr}; 
array_ptr = new int[10]; // allocate array on the heap
    
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    array_ptr[i] = i;
    std::cout<<array_ptr[i]<<std::endl;
}

delete [] array_ptr; // deletes allocated space
```

To my understanding, `int *array_ptr` displays the actual value, whereas `int array_ptr` with no dereference operator displays the address in memory.

So, how come `array_ptr[i]` displays 0 1 2 3 4 ... 10, instead of displaying address 1000, 1004, 1008...etc. (address nr made up).

Comment: Because you're dereferencing it:  `array_ptr[i]`

Comment: it is not dereferenced, array_ptr points to an address, when you dereference *array_ptr should display an actual value

Comment: `array_ptr[i]` is equivalent with doing `*(array_ptr + i)`. So what would you call it if not _dereferencing_?

Comment: You don't print the pointer `array_ptr` you print an element in the array it points to `array_ptr[i]`.

Comment: Amazing, now I understand it, thanks a lot

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than initializing them with placeholder values and immediately overwriting the placeholder. In this case that means changing `int *array_ptr{nullptr}; array_ptr = new int[10];` to `int *array_ptr = new int[10];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointer's mean is "Which value is in the indicating adress?"

If you want to see addressing of variables you have to use & operator.

Try this in the for loop

```
std::cout << &array_ptr[i] << std::endl;
```

Comment: Or simply `array_ptr + i`, which is easier understandable.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It works too. @πάνταῥεῖ